# I am getting the Error ArtifactVersionNotFound while deploying VM or starting a VM from Stopped(De-Allocated) state

Tags: azure

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"ArtifactVersionNotFound","message":"No version found in the artifact repository that satisfies the requested version '' for VM extension with publisher 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.GuestAgent' and type 'CRPProd'."}]}

Comment: This isn’t a software development problem, and this isn’t appropriate for Stack Overflow. Usually, a question regarding Azure administrativen might be appropriate for the Server Fault site. But this seems pretty clearly to be a support issue best raised with Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with VM's in Azure.

> **Virtual Machines - Investigating**
>
> **Impact Statement**: Starting at 07:00 UTC on 13 Oct 2021, a subset of customers using Windows Virtual Machines may experience failure notifications when performing service management operations - such as start, create, update, delete. Deployments of new VMS and any updates to extensions may fail. Non-Windows Virtual Machines, and existing running Windows Virtual Machines should not be impacted by this issue.
>
> **Current Status**: We are aware of this issue and are actively investigating the issue. The next update will be provided within 60 minutes, or as events warrant.
>
> This message was last updated at 08:52 UTC on 13 October 2021

More details: [Azure status](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status)